# Laravel: Retrieve records from a table with an associated table via another table

Tags: laravel, database, eloquent, get, has-one-through

here is my problem.

I have 3 tables:

1. bookings (id, spot_id,...)

a booking have one spot and a spot have multiple bookings

2. spots (id, place_id,...)

a spot have one place and a place have multiple spots

3. places(id, ...)

And what i want is from the BookingController get
a list of bookings with their associated places

somethings like that:

`Booking::where("ok",1)->with("place")->get();`

i already have the "hasMany" and "belongsTo" relations in all three models. And i already tried "hasOneThrough" in booking model but to no avail.

how can i do that thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want to have the places included in the booking model you can add those as an attribute:

```
namespace App\Models;

class Booking{
    public $appends = ['places'];

    public function getPlacesAttribute()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Place::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can acces places directly from the booking class like $booking->places